# Does $|x^*|=|x|$ in a star ring with an absolute value?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, absolute-value, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a [star ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_ring) with an [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29). Is it true that $|x^*|=|x|$ for all $x\in R$?

Here a star ring is a ring with a function $*:R\to R$ called conjugation such that

- $(x+y)^*=x^*+y^*$
- $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$
- $x^{**}=x,$

and an absolute value is a function $|\cdot|:R\to\Bbb R$ such that

- $|x|=0\iff x=0$
- $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$
- $|xy|=|x||y|.$

Obviously it is true for the trivial conjugation $x^*=x$, and it is also true for $\Bbb C$ and matrix rings over $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ with transposition and any of the various common matrix norms, so I wonder if it is true in general.

Comment: Your definition is slightly wrong. According to Wiki, you need $1^{\ast}=1$

Comment: @avid19 It is derivable: $1^*=1\cdot1^*=1^{**}1^*=(1\cdot 1^*)^*=1^{**}=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily the case. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17})$ forms a star ring with absolute value under the conjugation $(a+b\sqrt{17})^*=a-b\sqrt{17}$ and the standard (Euclidean) absolute value, but certainly $|1+\sqrt{17}|\neq |1-\sqrt{17}|$.